# How serialize the first property of a MongoDB document?

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, bson

I have the following MongoDB document "identifications" that has a variable property.

1-

```
"identifications" : {
                    "a" : {
                            "type" : "a",
                            "value" : "x1"
                    }
            }
```

2-

```
 "identifications" : {
                    "a" : {
                            "type" : "a",
                            "value" : "x2"
                    }
            }
```

3-

```
 "identifications" : {
                    "b" : {
                            "type" : "b",
                            "value" : "x3"
                    }
              }
```

4-

```
    "identifications" : {
                    "c" : {
                            "type" : "c",
                            "value" : "x4"
                    }
              }
```

I want to serialize the identifications document in a BSONType for C# Driver. The way i thought was

```
public class Identifications
{
    [BsonElement(Order = 1)]
    public Property prop { get; set; }
}
```

But it returns me a null value. There is something to take the element with no matter of its name?